# Installing MySQL Connector/C in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql, gcc

I have downloaded 'Linux - Generic (glibc 2.12) (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive' from [here on dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) and am following [this tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-c/en/connector-c-installation-source-unix.html).
On invoking the command `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"` the following error is reported:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/media/temporary/Downloads/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Please suggest a method or a tutorial if available, to install MySQL Connector/C.

Comment: `Linux - Generic (glibc 2.12) (x86, 64-bit)` is not a source package.

Comment: Just get `default-libmysqlclient-dev` with `apt`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Where may I find the source package for installation? Are there any other methods to install MySQL Connector/C in Ubuntu 16.04 or is it there in apt-repository?